# How to center labels on X-Axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, bar-chart

I want to plot 2 bars for 3 evaluations. The X-axis is symbolic which seems to cause a lot of problems when you want to center the labels on the x-axis.

[image]

The labels are not centered below the tick value except the one in the middel. I though this would be a rather easy plot. Except for the labels the plot is actually like I want it. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Here a MWE of my plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}    

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        ymin=60,  
        ymax=100,
        ybar,
        enlarge x limits=0.4,
%        bar width=1mm, 
        width=11.5cm,
        height=10cm, 
        xlabel={Accuracy \%},
        symbolic x coords={A $\rightarrow$ B,B $\rightarrow$ C,C $\rightarrow$ D},
        xtick=data,
%       bar shift=0pt
  ]

%50.0 entries are dummies otherwise the other labels do not even appear on the axis
\addplot[fill=orange] coordinates {(A $\rightarrow$ B,96.0)(B $\rightarrow$ C,50.0)(C $\rightarrow$ D,50.0)};
\addplot[fill=black] coordinates {(A $\rightarrow$ B,92.3)(B $\rightarrow$ C,50.0)(C $\rightarrow$ D,50.0)};

\addplot[fill=orange] coordinates {(B $\rightarrow$ C,88.9)};
\addplot[fill=black] coordinates {(B $\rightarrow$ C,73.6)};

\addplot[fill=orange] coordinates {(C $\rightarrow$ D,90.6)};
\addplot[fill=black] coordinates {(C $\rightarrow$ D,80.8)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood a bit, instead of the dummy values use the actual numbers from the other `addplot`s, and remove the last four `\addplot`s altogether. Each `\addplot` represents a series of values, and for bar plots `pgfplots` makes room for all the series at each x-coordinate. With six `\addplot`s, `pgfplots` makes room for six bars, but you only fill two of them at each coordinate.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        ymin=60,  
        ymax=100,
        ybar,
        enlarge x limits=0.4,
%        bar width=1mm, 
        width=11.5cm,
        height=10cm, 
        xlabel={Accuracy \%},
        symbolic x coords={A $\rightarrow$ B,B $\rightarrow$ C,C $\rightarrow$ D},
        xtick=data,
%       bar shift=0pt
  ]

\addplot[fill=orange] coordinates {(A $\rightarrow$ B,96.0)(B $\rightarrow$ C,88.9)(C $\rightarrow$ D,90.6)};
\addplot[fill=black] coordinates {(A $\rightarrow$ B,92.3)(B $\rightarrow$ C,73.6)(C $\rightarrow$ D,80.8)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is close. For reference, review the example on p84 of the `pgfplots` manual. You need to correct the way you have organized the data to be plotted. each `addplot` needs to be given the sequential series of co-ordinates for A-> B, B->C and C->D.

Here is the code that produces the desired graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}    

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        ymin=60,  
        ymax=100,
        ybar,
        enlarge x limits=0.4,
%        bar width=1mm, 
        width=11.5cm,
        height=10cm, 
        xlabel={Accuracy \%},
        symbolic x coords={A $\rightarrow$ B,B $\rightarrow$ C,C $\rightarrow$ D},
        xtick=data,
%       bar shift=0pt
  ]

\addplot[fill=orange] coordinates {(A $\rightarrow$ B,96.0) (B $\rightarrow$ C,88.9) (C $\rightarrow$ D,90.6)};
\addplot[fill=black] coordinates {(A $\rightarrow$ B,92.3) (B $\rightarrow$ C,73.6) (C $\rightarrow$ D,80.8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]