# X labels not right! pgfplots bar chart

Tags: pgfplots

I am pretty new to pgfplots, and I am attempting to make a bar chart using, but the xtick labels are not appearing with respect to the bars.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{What Do You Do When You Are Bored?}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    grid style=dashed,
    axis lines=left,
    enlargelimits=0.5,
    ymin=0,
    ytick={0,.1,.2,.3,.4},
    bar width=1cm,
    xtick={18 \& under,19-64 ,65+,all ages}
    axis lines=left,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
 anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Popularity},
    symbolic x coords={18 \& under,19-64,65+,all ages},
    xtick={18 \& under,19-64,65+,all ages},
    nodes near coords, 
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(18 \& under,.314)};
    \addplot coordinates {(19-64,0.2058333333333)};
    \addplot coordinates {(65+,.18)};
    \addplot coordinates {(all ages,.2255)};
    \legend{Texting, Watching TV, Reading, Talking with friends}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

However, as you can see the x labels are not anywhere near the bars. Any help would be great.

As a side note, how would I decrease the amount of space between the x axis and the beginning of the bars?

Comment: The problem with the xticklabels is essentially the same as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335126/how-to-center-labels-on-x-axis/335130#335130: use a single `\addplot`. For the spacing, instead of `enlargelimits=0.5`, use `enlarge x limits=0.5`, and optionally add `enlarge y limits=<some value>` if you need more vertical space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, I added `enlarge y limits` and `enlarge x limits` and `ybar=-1cm` in the `axis` options.
The first two commands set the x and y limits of the plot and the last one sets the space between the bars.
I also included `title=...` inside the plot instead of using `figure` environment and adding `caption`. I hope it's what you were looking for.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=newest}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        title=What Do You Do When You Are Bored?,
        ybar=-1cm, % because of bar width=1cm
        axis lines=left,
        enlarge y limits=0.1,
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={0,.1,.2,.3,.4},
        bar width=1cm,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={Popularity},
        symbolic x coords={18 \& under,19-64,65+,all ages},  
        xtick={18 \& under,19-64,65+,all ages},  
        nodes near coords, 
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(18 \& under,.314)};
        \addplot coordinates {(19-64,0.2058333333333)};
        \addplot coordinates {(65+,.18)};
        \addplot coordinates {(all ages,.2255)};
        \legend{Texting, Watching TV, Reading, Talking with friends}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```